# Windows client connecting to UCS / Samba server - The join operation was not successful

Tags: linux, active-directory, samba, windows-server, domaincontroller

Using Univention Corporate Server `UCS`,
I have the following Linux distribution:

```
root@ucs:~# cat /etc/*-release
DISTRIB_ID=Univention
DISTRIB_RELEASE="4.2-2 errata159"
DISTRIB_CODENAME=Lesum

DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Univention Corporate Server 4.2-2 errata159 (Lesum)"
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

and the following Samba version:

```
root@ucs:~# samba -V
Version 4.6.1-Debian
```

On this Linux machine I have configured the package:

```
Active Directory-compatible Domain Controller
```

I configured one user there: `myuser` which is under the group: `Domain Users`.

My problem is, when trying to connect to the local domain defined there: `mydomain.intranet`

I get the error:

```
The join operation was not successful. This could be because an existing computer account having name "MYUSER-PC" was previously created using a different set of credentials. Use a different computer name, or contact your administrator to remove any stale conflicting account. The error was:

Access is denied
```

as you can see on the following image:

[image]

Any idea on how to troubleshoot this?

Thanks.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Manually reposted: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/391622/windows-client-connecting-to-ucs-samba-server-the-join-operation-was-not-suc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Greetings from Univention,

this might not be the best Site to ask for solutions for these kind of problems, as Jeff already mention.

We would like to invite you to [Univention Help](https://help.univention.com/) where a lot of greatly experienced Community members and our Staff would love to help you.

Beside that, did you try to join your domain with your `myuser` user? This won't work as your user doesn't have the proper rights to add Machines to your Domain. Have you tried it with the User `Administrator` as shown in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeJSm.png)?

You also want to make sure, that there isn't already a Machine with the name `DELL-INSIPRON` existent in your domain, but I assume that this won't be the case.